# Tooltip callbacks in line chart JS not working

Tags: javascript, callback, chart.js

I'm using line chart js to display a graph and I'm trying to calculate the difference between the selected point and the previous one and render it in a tool tip.

I've read that I should use callbacks function but when I tried it nothing happen.

Even I only try to change the tittle
Here's my options for my line chart if anyone can help :)
Chart js version : 3.6.1

```
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      font: {
        size: 18,
      },
      color: "white"
    },
    zoom: {
      zoom: {
        drag: {
          enabled: true
        },
        mode: 'xy',
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function () {
          return "my tittle";
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Not your case but for me the problem was that I'm using another plugin, `stacked100`, which was already replacing the tooltip, that's why my callbacks were not being called. This plugin offers `replaceTooltipLabel : false` so you can customize the tooltip with callbacks the way you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using V2 syntax in with V3, you can read the namespace in the [options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/tooltip.html).

Tooltip has been moved to the plugins section

For all changes please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: () => ('Title')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Even in the plugins section the callback is still not working

When I try with the backgroundColor it's working but the title "Before title" never appears in this example

`plugins: {
    tooltip:{
      backgroundColor: "white",
      callbacks : {
        beforeTitle: function(context) {
          return 'before title';
        }
      }
    },`